# Apache2 RateLimit not working as expacted

Tags: apache2, rate-limiting

Well hello!

So I recently created a Cloud on my Server.. which works fine. But there is one, JUST ONE thing I cant get to work correctly.. and thats the rate-limit.

I tried the rate-limit module with the following code in my VirtualHost file.. but it somehow does not work how I want it to...

```
<Location "/downloads">
   SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
   SetEnv rate-limit 400 
</Location>
```

So, if I set the rate-limit to 1 or 10, it works like a charm.. it limits it to 1 or 10 KB/s, if I set it to 20.. it somehow is 40 KB/s.. and If I set it to 50, it just seems likes it's off.. because I get my normal download speed of 2 MB/s on files.

What am I doing wrong? Yes the module is enabled of course. I did also try the bw module, but thats also not what I want.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and the newest apache version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't you mixed data download speed and traffic throughput? There is always some overhead when downloadding/uploading data.

Comment: What do you mean by mixed? Also "some" overhead? From 50KB/S to 2 MB/S? Thats not "some"

Comment: Sorry, I have missed your point. Did you test it on a local machine or on a remote one?

Comment: I have a VPS server hosted on contabo. There I set everything up.

Comment: Any other idea why it's not working?